Latex compilation and user download of PDF on Azure App Service (or other service)
Our company currently has several web applications deployed on Azure App Services (using .NET Framework). We have a use case to generate user-specific PDF documents that can be downloaded by the user. One possibility I am exploring is to generate TEX and PNG files programmatically and then compile them to PDF using pdflatex (or similar). Ideally, I would like to do this on an Azure App Service if possible but I am open to alternatives.
The main work flow would be something along the lines of:

User calls API endpoint requesting a PDF
Server-side code retrieves user-specific information from database and generates TEX and PNG files programmatically.
Server calls pdflatex (or similar) to compile PDF and writes it (somewhere). Also, temporary files will need to be written somewhere and cleaned up after.
User can then download compiled PDF.

There are a number of issues here that I am not sure can be dealt with using an App Service (so any suggestions of alternative methods would be welcome).

Firstly, the server code would have to write the TEX and PNG files to some temporary location.
A Latex compiler and any required libraries would have to be installed somewhere and be invoked from the server code. The compiler would also need access to the stored TEX and PNG files.
The Latex compiler would need to be able to write auxiliary files to a temporary location.
The compiled PDF would have to be written somewhere (possibly a remote storage location)
The PDF document should be downloadable by the user.

At present, I do not know if any of the above is possible on an App Service, or if it is how to accomplish it. I was thinking of perhaps doing all of this on a virtual machine but I was hoping that there would be a cheaper / more efficient way of doing this. Perhaps an Azure function - but I have no experience with these.
Any advice/suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Please note though that I am looking for ways of implementing Latex on Azure, rather than looking for alternative ways of generating PDFs.
